# Maximum number of values in an array of 10 Swift / Firebase

Tags: arrays, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

This system of subscriptions and subscribers as in Instagram, when one of my users subscribed to 11 users, the application began to crash for him with the error Thread 1:

> Invalid Query. The 'in' filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value array.".

To avoid repetitive questions, I looked at all similar questions and none of the methods helped me

import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import ProgressHUD

```
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = true
    @Published var user: User
    @Published var followedUsers = [User]()
    @Published var followersUsers = [User]()
    @Published var followedUsersAny = [User]()
    @Published var followersUsersAny = [User]()

    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
        fetchFollowedUsers()
        fetchFollowersUsers()
        fetchFollowedUsersAny()
        fetchFollowersUsersAny()
    }
}

extension ProfileViewModel {
 func fetchFollowedUsers() {
        self.isLoading = true
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        COLLECTION_USERS.document(currentUid).collection("following").getDocuments { followersSnapshot, _ in
            guard let followerDocuments = followersSnapshot?.documents else { return }
            let followedUsers = followerDocuments.map({ $0.documentID })
            
            if !followedUsers.isEmpty {
                COLLECTION_USERS.whereField("uid", in: followedUsers).getDocuments { tweetsSnapshot, _ in
                    guard let tweetDocuments = tweetsSnapshot?.documents else { return }
                    self.followedUsers = tweetDocuments.map({ User(dictionary: $0.data()) })
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
            } else {
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//Page that displays the number of subscriptions

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserFollowedView: View {
    let emptyFollowing : LocalizedStringKey = "emptyFollowing"
    let emptyFollowingAny: LocalizedStringKey = "emptyFollowingAny"
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ProfileViewModel
    let user : User
    
    init(user: User){
        self.user = user
        self.viewModel = ProfileViewModel(user: user)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            if AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid == user.id {
                if viewModel.followedUsers.isEmpty {
                    Text(emptyFollowing)
                } else {
                    VStack {
                        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                            ForEach(viewModel.followedUsers) { user in
                                NavigationLink {
                                    UserProfileView(user: user)
                                } label: {
                                    UserCell(user: user)
                                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        .padding()
                                        .padding(.horizontal, 1)
                                        .padding(.vertical, 2)
                                        .background(
                                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                                .fill(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                                                .shadow(color: Color(UIColor.systemPurple).opacity(0.3), radius: 7, x: 0, y: 4)
                                        )
                                    //                                        .padding()
                                        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
                                        .padding(.vertical, 1)
                                        .padding(.bottom, 4)
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if viewModel.followedUsersAny.isEmpty {
                    Text(emptyFollowingAny)
                } else {
                    VStack {
                        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                            ForEach(viewModel.followedUsersAny) { user in
                                NavigationLink {
                                    UserProfileView(user: user)
                                } label: {
                                    UserCell(user: user)
                                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        .padding()
                                        .padding(.horizontal, 1)
                                        .padding(.vertical, 2)
                                        .background(
                                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                                .fill(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                                                .shadow(color: Color(UIColor.systemPurple).opacity(0.3), radius: 7, x: 0, y: 4)
                                        )
                                    //                                        .padding()
                                        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
                                        .padding(.vertical, 1)
                                        .padding(.bottom, 4)
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show the full error messages you get and on which line of the code.
What is `The in filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value array.`? 
Note, you should use `@StateObject var viewModel: ProfileViewModel` in your `UserFollowedView` and declare it like this: 
`@StateObject var viewModel = ProfileViewModel()`, then use something like `.onAppear { viewModel.user = user }` to set the `user`.

Answer (score 0):

> Maximum number of values in an array of 10.

That's not correct. You can add as many values as you want in an array as long as the size of the document is less than [1 Mib](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

You're getting the following error:

> Invalid Query. The 'in' filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value array.

Because most likely your `followedUsers` array contains more than 10 elements and this is currently not supported, hence the error.

A workaround would be to retrieve the documents in batches, and then process the results from each batch on the client. Perhaps you can also try to model the data into a single aggregated document, as long as you stay under the above limitation.